# Refactor Laravel Routes

Tags: laravel-5

I am having partial success refactoring common laravel routes to a class. Currently I error looking for the controller.

Here is the basic pattern I am refactoring. I will need the same pattern for `vendors`, `users`, `terminals` etc

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['csrf','DashboardAuthenticate'], 'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers'], function () {

    Route::get('vendors/', 'VendorController@index');
    Route::get('vendors/create', 'VendorController@create');
    Route::get('vendors/{id}', 'VendorController@show');
    Route::post('vendors/search', 'VendorController@search');
    Route::put('vendors/', 'VendorController@update');
    Route::delete('vendors/', 'VendorController@destroy');

    Route::get('roles/', 'RoleController@index');
    Route::get('roles/create', 'RoleController@create');
    Route::get('roles/{id}', 'RoleController@show');
    Route::post('roles/search', 'RoleController@search');
    Route::put('roles/', 'RoleController@update');
    Route::delete('roles/', 'RoleController@destroy');

    Route::get('users/', 'UserController@index');
    Route::get('users/create', 'UserController@create');
    Route::get('users/{id}', 'UserController@show');
    Route::post('users/search', 'UserController@search');
    Route::put('users/', 'UserController@update');
    Route::delete('users/', 'UserController@destroy');

    Route::get('terminals/', 'TerminalController@index');
    Route::get('terminals/create', 'TerminalController@create');
    Route::get('terminals/{id}', 'TerminalController@show');
    Route::post('terminals/search', 'TerminalController@search');
    Route::put('terminals/', 'TerminalController@update');
    Route::delete('terminals/', 'TerminalController@destroy');
});
```

To refactor I made a class that looks like: (the CIRoute class file is under App\Classes\Routes namespace)

```
class CIRoutes
{
    public static function addRoutes($name)
    {
        $n2 = ucfirst($name);
        Route::get($name.'s/', $n2.'Controller@index');
        Route::get($name.'s/create', $n2.'Controller@create');
        Route::get($name.'s/{id}', $n2.'Controller@show');
        Route::post($name.'s/search', $n2.'Controller@search');
        Route::put($name.'s/', $n2.'Controller@update');
        Route::delete($name.'s/', $n2.'Controller@destroy');
    }
}
```

Then I create the route:

```
CIRoutes::addRoutes('vendors');
```

I thought this was working fine, but I was mistaken. Currently `php artisan route:list` comes back with `Class App\Http\Controllers\RolesController does not exist` which it does - i mean it works fine without the refactor.

How can I refactor the common route pattern?

Comment: this code works correctly - I was calling the route with the plural of the model name, which is incorrect . `CIRoutes::addRoutes('users');` should be `CIRoutes::addRoutes('user');` . duh duh duh

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a better option to store your routes in the **routes/web.php** file instead of a class, and use the group method to organize them instead.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'vendors'], function () {

    Route::get('/', function ()    {
        // Matches The "/vendors/" URL
    });
    Route::get('/create', function ()    {
        // Matches The "/vendors/create" URL
    });

});
```

Group also allows for middleware, sub-domain and namespace routing.

Next, since your class is creating a typical CRUD route, you can simply use:

```
Route::resource('vendors', 'VendorsController');
```

To create the following routes:

```
Verb        URI                     Action        Route Name
GET         /vendors                index         vendors.index
GET         /vendors/create         create        vendors.create
POST        /vendors                store         vendors.store
GET         /vendors/{vendor}       show          vendors.show
GET         /vendors/{vendor}/edit  edit          vendors.edit
PUT/PATCH   /vendors/{vendor}       update        vendors.update
DELETE      /vendors/{vendor}       destroy       vendors.destroy
```

---

Note that Laravel automatically maps all the routes in **routes/web.php** to your **'web' middleware** and the **App\Http\Controllers** namespace in the *App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider* class.

```
/**
 * Define the "web" routes for the application.
 *
 * These routes all receive session state, CSRF protection, etc.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function mapWebRoutes()
{
    Route::group([
        'middleware' => 'web',
        'namespace' => $this->namespace,
    ], function ($router) {
        require base_path('routes/web.php');
    });
}
```

So if you still want to use a class to define your routes, you will have to group the routes in your class and assign them the App\Http\Controllers namespace and the 'web' middleware.

The web middleware makes sure that these routes provides features like session state and CSRF protection.

So you could probably (I haven't tested it) do something like:

```
public static function addRoutes($name)
{

    Route::group([
        'middleware' => 'web',
        'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers',
    ], function () use ($name) {

        $n2 = ucfirst($name);
        Route::get($name.'s/', $n2.'Controller@index');
        Route::get($name.'s/create', $n2.'Controller@create');
        Route::get($name.'s/{id}', $n2.'Controller@show');
        Route::post($name.'s/search', $n2.'Controller@search');
        Route::put($name.'s/', $n2.'Controller@update');
        Route::delete($name.'s/', $n2.'Controller@destroy');

    });

}
```

Comment: All good stuff... I had been using route::resource, my routes are just a bit different as I am adding in /search and I do not use /edit... js handles that. I was attempting to add in my own 'resource' function. My routes are under middleware protection, I did not show you that in my example. They are also grouped under a namespace.  Your final example then is exactly what I was attempting, which leads me to controller does not exist.

Comment: @CraigIannazzi Have you defined the namespace?

Comment: Yeah I updated my question so you can see the namespace. I also moved the namespace into `CIRoutes` to see if that was the issue. Then I dug into laravel source to look at how route::resource was created. Pretty lost there, Its looking like I will have a huge route file.

Comment: @CraigIannazzi Wait, where is your CIRoutes class located? Is it getting autoloaded? Also, did you group the routes in your CIRoutes addRoutes() function too, because that's where the namespace needs to be set (as in my example)

Comment: Dude it was because I was adding an 's' to the end of the route... it should be CIRoute::('vendor') not 'vendors'. The obvious stuff KILLS me.

Comment: Hahaha damn! Those are the worst. Im glad you fixed it.

Comment: @CraigIannazzi were you able to create your own Route::resource function?

Comment: Yes - the code posted works correctly, I was simply calling it wrong - look at my comment for the question